# Draw image in canvas with jquery mobile

Tags: image, canvas, jquery-mobile

i would like to load 3 images in a canvas. I'm using jquery mobile since the site i'm building is for ipad so i cannot use $('document').ready() nor window.onload.
My code is as follow:

```
$('#pageId').live('pagecreate', function () {
var contextE = document.getElementById('gauge-e').getContext('2d');
var background = new Image();
background.src = gaugeImagePath + "bg.png";
var green = new Image();
green.src = gaugeImagePath + "green.png";
var grey = new Image();
greye.src = gaugeImagePath + "grey.png";
foreground = new Image();
foreground.src = gaugeImagePath + "fg.png";

contextE.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
contextE.drawImage(green, 0, 0);
contextE.drawImage(grey, 0, 0);
contextE.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0);
```

});

I think i need to bind the image loading to the page create event but images are not getting loaded. I cannot see anything in the canvas.
How can i make them load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that fires when any of them load. It will fire 4 times, so they will each appear on screen as they load.

```
gaugeEBackground.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeGreenENeedle.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeGreyENeedle.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeEForeground.onload = hasLoaded;

function hasLoaded() {
    // draw whatever ones have loaded so far:
    contextE.drawImage(gaugeEBackground, 0, 0);
    contextE.drawImage(gaugeGreenENeedle, 0, 0);
    contextE.drawImage(gaugeGreyENeedle, 0, 0);
    contextE.drawImage(gaugeEForeground, 0, 0);      
}
```

live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChuRn/

Comment: This is correct, however it's not enough to make it work with jquery mobile 1.0 rc2.
To make it, you'll have to bind to pageinit event.
I'll write the correct answer down:
$('#leafMeter').live('pageinit', function (event) {
gaugeEBackground.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeGreenENeedle.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeGreyENeedle.onload = hasLoaded;
gaugeEForeground.onload = hasLoaded;

function hasLoaded() {
    // draw whatever ones have loaded so far:
    contextE.drawImage(gaugeEBackground, 0, 0);
     
}